# Camel HBase and remote hbase server

Tags: java, apache-camel, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to use Camel Hbase component (2.15) to connect with remote HBase server.  (Ports are reachable and tested with telnet).  I took sample abase-site.xml and updated it with quorum and port number of zookeeper.  But no luck.

Please help.

HBase-site.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.msginterval</name>
    <value>1000</value>
    <description>Interval between messages from the RegionServer to HMaster
    in milliseconds.  Default is 15. Set this value low if you want unit
    tests to be responsive.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.pause</name>
    <value>5000</value>
    <description>General client pause value.  Used mostly as value to wait
    before running a retry of a failed get, region lookup, etc.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.meta.thread.rescanfrequency</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>How long the HMaster sleeps (in milliseconds) between scans of
    the root and meta tables.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.server.thread.wakefrequency</name>
    <value>1000</value>
    <description>Time to sleep in between searches for work (in milliseconds).
    Used as sleep interval by service threads such as META scanner and log roller.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.handler.count</name>
    <value>5</value>
    <description>Count of RPC Server instances spun up on RegionServers
    Same property is used by the HMaster for count of master handlers.
    Default is 10.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.lease.period</name>
    <value>6000</value>
    <description>Length of time the master will wait before timing out a region
    server lease. Since region servers report in every second (see above), this
    value has been reduced so that the master will notice a dead region server
    sooner. The default is 30 seconds.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
    <value>-1</value>
    <description>The port for the hbase master web UI
    Set to -1 if you do not want the info server to run.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.info.port</name>
    <value>-1</value>
    <description>The port for the hbase regionserver web UI
    Set to -1 if you do not want the info server to run.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.info.port.auto</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Info server auto port bind. Enables automatic port
    search if hbase.regionserver.info.port is already in use.
    Enabled for testing to run multiple tests on one machine.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.lease.thread.wakefrequency</name>
    <value>3000</value>
    <description>The interval between checks for expired region server leases.
    This value has been reduced due to the other reduced values above so that
    the master will notice a dead region server sooner. The default is 15 seconds.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.optionalcacheflushinterval</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>
    Amount of time to wait since the last time a region was flushed before
    invoking an optional cache flush. Default 60,000.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.safemode</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
    Turn on/off safe mode in region server. Always on for production, always off
    for tests.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.hregion.max.filesize</name>
    <value>67108864</value>
    <description>
    Maximum desired file size for an HRegion.  If filesize exceeds
    value + (value / 2), the HRegion is split in two.  Default: 256M.

    Keep the maximum filesize small so we split more often in tests.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.log.dir</name>
    <value>${user.dir}/../logs</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
    <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
    The port at which the clients will connect.
    </description>
  </property>
   <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quoru</name>
    <value>192.168.0.87</value>
    <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
    The port at which the clients will connect.
    </description>
  </property>
  
</configuration>
```

Java DSL:

```
from("direct:doAddDeviceTask")
        .process(new LoggerProcessor())
        .to("hbase:sugartone_deviceinfo?operation=CamelHBasePut");
```